# Agrupar json data por um determinado objeto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo uma lista:

```
var dataString='[ 
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 5, "bytes" : 50189 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 17308 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 47412 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 7601 },
 { "category" : "Business", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2847 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 24210 },
 { "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 6, "bytes" : 613036 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2858 } 
]';
```

onde `category` é um padrao variante que me importa, eu queria agrupar estes, o resto é variante nao padrao que nao me importa.

Agrupar tipo uma array apenas de `Business` em que eu possa percorrer em todos os business se eu quiser e por ai vai..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Criei um exemplo que agrupa os elementos do array, pela propriedade `category` de cada item, criando um objeto em que cada chave é um grupo contendo os elementos correspondentes:

```js
var dataString= '['+
 '{ "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 5, "bytes" : 50189 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 17308 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 47412 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 7601 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Business", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2847 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 24210 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 6, "bytes" : 613036 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2858 } '+
']';

var data = JSON.parse(dataString);

var groupedData = {};

for (var it = 0; it < data.length; it++) {
  var item = data[it];
  if (!groupedData[item.category])
    groupedData[item.category] = [];
  groupedData[item.category].push(item);
}

document.body.innerHTML = "";
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(groupedData, null, 4)));
```

```css
body { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
```

Comment: Gostei de seu método para imprimir `JSON` no `DOM` `html`, é domínio publico? Já utilizei em minha resposta. Hehe. E +1 pela resposta.

Comment: @Fernando Como assim *"domínio publico"*... eu usei apenas recursos do browser. Fique a vontade para usar onde quiser. =)

Comment: Sim, sim! Eu sei, tava só me referindo por ter utilizado de forma `copy` `paste`. Mas serio agora, o terceiro parâmetro do [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), não conhecia, muito inteligente o recurso.

Comment: Eu também não conhecia, descobri ao produzir esta resposta... ao procurar uma forma de fazer JSON bonitinho. Ai descobri que o browser já é capaz de fazer isso... maneiro né!

Answer (score 2):

É uma solução que traz um resultado final idêntico ao da [resposta @MiguelAngelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56706/2998), só que utilizando uma biblioteca que gosto muito e utilizo algum tempo (que aparentemente está abandonada pelo desenvolvedor) o [jLinq.js](http://hugoware.net/projects/jlinq).

A implementação seria assim:

```js
var dataString= '['+
 '{ "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 5, "bytes" : 50189 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 17308 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 47412 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 7601 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Business", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2847 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 24210 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 6, "bytes" : 613036 },'+
 '{ "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2858 } '+
']';

var data = JSON.parse(dataString);

var result = jlinq.from(data)
                  // para ser case sensitive
                  .useCase()
                  // aplica group pelo campo categoria
                  .group("category");

// para imprimir do DOM (copiado na cara dura da implementação do @MiguelAngelo)
document.body.innerHTML = "";
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)));
```

```css
body { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<script src="http://hugoware.net/resources/projects/jlinq/jlinq.min.demo-version.js"></script>
```

> [Exemplo também disponível aqui no jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/gjmbp0tq/1/)

**Vantagens da biblioteca**

Você tem muitos mais recursos disponíveis além do group, como podemos ver [aqui na demo](http://hugoware.net/projects/jlinq/demo) e no [arquivo de teste da biblioteca](https://github.com/hugoware/jlinq-beta/blob/master/test.js).

Comment: Isso é como se fosse o linq do .net? Muito doido sua resposta.

Comment: Ser, ser não é, mas acredito que ideia do autor era essa. Hehe. Mas é bem bacana de utilizar e similar ao Linq do .net, ajuda muito, e funciona perfeito e rápido, para o que se propõe. Só está um pouco abandonado pelos autores que desde de 2011 não tem mas nenhum commit no github. (Eu mesmo já adicionei alguns funcionalidades, em minha versão local, talvez futuramente commito no github)

Comment: Mto obrigado pela explicação, concerteza vou procurar saber um pouco mais.