# Agrupamento dinâmico de dados JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, lógica

Tenho tentado ha alguns dias efetuar o agrupamento de dados JSON dinâmicamente, mas sem sucesso, é uma questão mais de lógica do que de programação propriamente dita.

Dado um array de objetos(Usuarios), agrupa-los de acordo com seus atributos(nome, idade, etc).

O agrupamento deve ser dinâmico e o resultado será exibido de acordo com o atributos escolhidos.

**JSON:**

```
var lUsuarios = [{
    "NOME":"ANTONIO CARLOS CURY",
    "IDADE": 28,
    "SEXO": "MASCULINO",
    "ADMINISTRADOR": true
},{
    "NOME":"CESAR SIQUEIRA JUNIOR",
    "IDADE": 23,
    "SEXO": "MASCULINO",
    "ADMINISTRADOR": false
},{
    "NOME":"ANDREI SALVADOR",
    "IDADE": 18,
    "SEXO": "MASCULINO",
    "ADMINISTRADOR": true
},{
    "NOME":"SERGIO MORO",
    "IDADE": 35,
    "SEXO": "MASCULINO",
    "ADMINISTRADOR": false
},{
    "NOME":"MARIA DA SILVA",
    "IDADE": 17,
    "SEXO": "FEMININO",
    "ADMINISTRADOR": true,
},{
    "NOME":"JOANA FINA",
    "IDADE": 19,
    "SEXO": "FEMININO",
    "ADMINISTRADOR": false
},{
    "NOME":"ELIANE DA SILVA",
    "IDADE": 21,
    "SEXO": "FEMININO",
    "ADMINISTRADOR": true,
},{
    "NOME":"MARIA BONITA",
    "IDADE": 47,
    "SEXO": "FEMININO",
    "ADMINISTRADOR": false
}]</code>
```

**Função agrupar:**

```
function AgruparJSON(colunas){
    //Throw new Exception("Não sei o que vai aqui");
}
```

**Chamada do método:**

*A grande dificuldade está nos agrupamentos compostos, onde irão ser agrupados por dois ou mais atributos da lista de usuários(JSON).*

```
$(function(){

    //JSON de dados dos usuários
    var lUsuarios = JSON.parse('[{...}]');

    var lUsuariosSexoAdministrador = lUsuarios.AgruparJSON("SEXO", "ADMINISTRADOR");    
    console.log(lUsuariosSexoAdministrador);

    //Resultado esperado para console.log(lUsuariosSexoAdministrador);
    [{"MASCULINO":
        [{ "true" : [{
                        "NOME":"ANTONIO CARLOS CURY",
                        "IDADE": 28,
                        "SEXO": "MASCULINO",
                        "ADMINISTRADOR": true
                    },{
                        "NOME":"ANDREI SALVADOR",
                        "IDADE": 18,
                        "SEXO": "MASCULINO",
                        "ADMINISTRADOR": true}]
        },{ "false": [{
                        "NOME":"CESAR SIQUEIRA JUNIOR",
                        "IDADE": 23,
                        "SEXO": "MASCULINO",
                        "ADMINISTRADOR": false
                    },{
                        "NOME":"SERGIO MORO",
                        "IDADE": 35,
                        "SEXO": "MASCULINO",
                        "ADMINISTRADOR": false
                    }]
        }]
    },{"FEMININO":
        [{ "true" : [{
                        "NOME":"MARIA DA SILVA",
                        "IDADE": 17,
                        "SEXO": "FEMININO",
                        "ADMINISTRADOR": true
                    },{
                        "NOME":"ELIANE DA SILVA",
                        "IDADE": 21,
                        "SEXO": "FEMININO",
                        "ADMINISTRADOR": true
                    }]
        },{ "false": [{
                        "NOME":"MARIA BONITA",
                        "IDADE": 47,
                        "SEXO": "FEMININO",
                        "ADMINISTRADOR": false
                    },{
                        "NOME":"JOANA FINA",
                        "IDADE": 19,
                        "SEXO": "FEMININO",
                        "ADMINISTRADOR": false
                    }]
        }]
    }]; 
});
```

Comment: [Algo assim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56704/agrupar-json-data-por-um-determinado-objeto)

Comment: Olá @GuilhermeCostamilam ! Obrigado pela resposta, eu já havia lido essa pergunta que me recomendou, o problema são os agrupamentos "filhos", para quando há mais de um agrupador, eles não respeitam os agrupadores "pais", necessito gerar os agrupadores "filhos" respeitando o agrupamento "Pai", conforme tentei mostrar na sáida do método: AgruparJSON("SEXO", "ADMINISTRADOR")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui vai um algoritmo simples que agrupa seus dados baseado em uma quantidade arbitrária de atributos:

```js
var lUsuarios=[{"NOME":"ANTONIO CARLOS CURY","IDADE":28,"SEXO":"MASCULINO","ADMINISTRADOR":true},{"NOME":"CESAR SIQUEIRA JUNIOR","IDADE":23,"SEXO":"MASCULINO","ADMINISTRADOR":false},{"NOME":"ANDREI SALVADOR","IDADE":18,"SEXO":"MASCULINO","ADMINISTRADOR":true},{"NOME":"SERGIO MORO","IDADE":35,"SEXO":"MASCULINO","ADMINISTRADOR":false},{"NOME":"MARIA DA SILVA","IDADE":17,"SEXO":"FEMININO","ADMINISTRADOR":true},{"NOME":"JOANA FINA","IDADE":19,"SEXO":"FEMININO","ADMINISTRADOR":false},{"NOME":"ELIANE DA SILVA","IDADE":21,"SEXO":"FEMININO","ADMINISTRADOR":true},{"NOME":"MARIA BONITA","IDADE":47,"SEXO":"FEMININO","ADMINISTRADOR":false}];

// complexidade aproximada de O(2N * C), onde:
// N = length de "lUsuarios"
// C = length de "colunas"
function AgruparJSON(colunas){
 var colsObjData = {};

 // 1. agrupamos por categorias em chaves que são a concatenação dos valores
 // das colunas desejas, something like "MASCULINO;true" ou "FEMININO;false"
 lUsuarios.forEach(function(userObj) {
  var key = colunas.reduce(function(a, b) {
   return (a ? a + ';' : a) + userObj[b];
  }, '');
  if (!(key in colsObjData)) {
   colsObjData[key] = [];
  }
  colsObjData[key].push(userObj);
 });

 // 2. já possuimos os agrupamentos, agora é apenas uma questão de transformar eles 
 // na estrutura desejada
 var finalData = {};
 for (var key in colsObjData) {
  var data = finalData;
  var splited = key.split(';');
  splited.forEach(function(col, index) {
   if (!(col in data)) {
    data[col] = {}
   }
   if (index === splited.length - 1) {
    data[col] = colsObjData[key];
   }
   else {
    data = data[col];
   }
  });
 }
 return finalData;
}

var result = AgruparJSON(["SEXO", "ADMINISTRADOR"]);
document.writeln(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Obs:

- O retorno de `AgruparJSON` não é exatamente no formato que você deseja, usei um modelo mais simples e compacto, mas que ainda preserva as propriedades de agrupamento. Se realmente precisar que seja no formato que postou na questão é simples converter.
- O algoritmo assume que todos os valores de dados no JSON são de tipos [primitivos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Valores_Primitivos). Seria possível extender para funcionar com outros tipos, mas aí dependeria de quais exatamente são eles.

Pretty print do resultado:

```
{
  "MASCULINO": {
    "true": [
        {
            "NOME": "ANTONIO CARLOS CURY",
            "IDADE": 28,
            "SEXO": "MASCULINO",
            "ADMINISTRADOR": true
        },
        {
            "NOME": "ANDREI SALVADOR",
            "IDADE": 18,
            "SEXO": "MASCULINO",
            "ADMINISTRADOR": true
        }
    ],
    "false": [
        {
            "NOME": "CESAR SIQUEIRA JUNIOR",
            "IDADE": 23,
            "SEXO": "MASCULINO",
            "ADMINISTRADOR": false
        },
        {
            "NOME": "SERGIO MORO",
            "IDADE": 35,
            "SEXO": "MASCULINO",
            "ADMINISTRADOR": false
        }
    ]
  },
  "FEMININO": {
    "true": [
        {
            "NOME": "MARIA DA SILVA",
            "IDADE": 17,
            "SEXO": "FEMININO",
            "ADMINISTRADOR": true
        },
        {
            "NOME": "ELIANE DA SILVA",
            "IDADE": 21,
            "SEXO": "FEMININO",
            "ADMINISTRADOR": true
        }
    ],
    "false": [
        {
            "NOME": "JOANA FINA",
            "IDADE": 19,
            "SEXO": "FEMININO",
            "ADMINISTRADOR": false
        },
        {
            "NOME": "MARIA BONITA",
            "IDADE": 47,
            "SEXO": "FEMININO",
            "ADMINISTRADOR": false
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! 
Ótimo trabalho, atende exatamente minha necessidade.

Answer (score -1):

Sei que faz tempo que respondi mas achei um modo de fazer o que eu queria, só pra atualizar aqui

```
function agruparJSON(coluna, valor) {
    var array = []
    for(i=0;i<lUsuarios.length;i++) {
        if (lUsuarios[i][coluna] == valor) {
            array.push(lUsuarios[i])
        }
    }
    return array
}

agruparJSON('SEXO', 'MASCULINO')
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Infelizmente sua solução não resolve meu problema, pois, os agrupadores devem ser dinâmicos. Na sua solução eu teria de criar um filtro para cada possível agrupador.

Comment: editei e ficou um pouco melhor, mas não é exatamente o que quer

Comment: achei um modo de fazer, porém esta limitado a um filtro por vez